# Is any way to force acedTraceBoundary returns always regions

Tags: autocad-plugin, objectarx

```
Acad::ErrorStatus acedTraceBoundary( const AcGePoint3d& seedPoint, bool detectIslands, AcDbVoidPtrArray& resultingBoundarySet )
```

[Here](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARXMAC/2017/ENU/?guid=OREFMAC-acedTraceBoundary_AcGePoint3d__bool_AcDbVoidPtrArray_) We can read that resultingBoundarySet : "Contains the resulting boundary in form of AcDbPolyline* objects" but sometimes we got set of AcDbRegions* (when boundary contains spline  maybe ). And Regions are what I need. Do You know any way to force `acedTraceBoundary` always create `AcDbRegion` not `AcDbPolylines` ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't way to force an acedTraceBoundary retrieve set of Plines alone, if in case if it is returning set of regions, you can always extract plines/primitive entities from a region.

Use [getSplitCurves](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARXMAC/2017/ENU/?guid=OREFMAC-AcDbCurve__getSplitCurves_AcGePoint3dArray__AcDbVoidPtrArray__const) on [AcDbRegion](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARXMAC/2017/ENU/?guid=OREFMAC-AcDbRegion)